# Tiff Image :How to set metadata for the mulltipage tiff programatically in .Net?

Tags: c#, image, metadata, tiff

I am trying to set metadata for multi-page tiff image. Below is code snippet setting metadata for single-page tiff image.

```
            Bitmap imageSource = img as Bitmap; // img is an original singlepage tiff image
            Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(imageSource.Width, imageSource.Height);

            try
            {
                ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");

                EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(2);                 
                EncoderParameter parameter = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT3);
                encoderParams.Param[0] = parameter;

                parameter = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag,(long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                encoderParams.Param[1] = parameter;

                //Set the resolution as of the image file
                tempBitmap.SetResolution(imageSource.HorizontalResolution, imageSource.VerticalResolution);

                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap))
                {
                    //Draw the image in the Empty bitmap by passing original imageSource
                    graphics.DrawImage(imageSource, 0, 0, (float)imageSource.Width, (float)imageSource.Height);
                }

                string strSign = "I am author";

                PropertyItem propItem = img.PropertyItems[0];
                propItem.Id = 315;  // this is called 'Author'
                propItem.Type = 2;
                propItem.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strSign + "\0");//signature;
                propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length;
                ((Image)tempBitmap).SetPropertyItem(propItem);
                img.Dispose();
                ((Image)tempBitmap).Save("sample.tif", encoderInfo, encoderParams);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
            }
```

This above code works fine for single-page image, but cant achieve setting metadata for multi-page image. I am bit new to this, any useful links or libraries available to achieve setting matadata for multi-page tiff image would be helpful.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
            }` Always a bad idea to hide any issues.

Comment: A similar routine should be applied to each frame. But you will need more involved code to create multiple frames. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130424080749/http://www.bobpowell.net:80/generating_multipage_tiffs.htm) is a copy is the much-referenced Bob Powell code.

Comment: @TaW went through it, but this link explains about, how to create multipage tiff file and not how to set matadata of multipage tiff.